# How to send confirmation code via SMS to user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms

In the Registration process, we need to send a confirmation code via SMS to the user. How is this done? Can you refer any SDK's or examples?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the subject is very interesting, in Stackoverflow you can only ask specific programming questions. Finding a tool to send SMSes is a job for popular search engines. Once you have found your gateway, feel free to ask here about any doubt

Comment: By the way, the moderation tools proposed me this question for closing just to **test** if I was paying attention. Hehe, it looks like I passed

Comment: @djechelon - Hi, i am unable to ask any questions.is it temporary or permanent ? cant i ask any further questions from this account ? any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

You are way off the mark. This should be done via a server side SMS gateway, this is not something that would be implemented on the phone.

Your app should send a request to a web server, which will work something out, then to validate the phone number, the server sends a text via the SMS gateway to the phone. The user would then take a value out of the text, input it into your app which will send it back to the server for comparison.

You will need to research this architecture a lot more

Comment: Thanks Simon.But is there any dedicated server for sending SMS to the specified Number.Sorry if my question is wrong.

Comment: @GreyCode there are many service providers of this, you will need to research it as there will be many factors such as what country you are in, will you be sending international texts, who offers the best rates, how easy they are to use etc etc

Comment: Yes.Good point.Also if we use any service providers it may cost for each SMS ? or is there any like No cost ?

Comment: @GreyCode no its going to cost, there could possibly be a free one but I can't imagine why anyone would set that up or what the catch is. If you need to validate a phone number its pretty much the only thing you can do, you can't ask a phone to send a text to itself and then ask the user did they get it. No platform would let you do this in the background, charging the user, requires showing the user a dialog that they can agree too, at which point they would see the security code anyway, defeating the point

Comment: I didn't mention as sending message from the same user who is going to receive.i asked like any `API` would send it likewise.please understand it clearly. Don't always underEstimate others.Nobody would ask with Zero percent of Knowledge About Objective c and iOS.

Comment: @GreyCode you've tagged the question as objective-c and xcode asking for an SDK to send a text to a user, nowhere did you refer to any kind of backend implementation, didn't ask for a service provider, didnt even mention the word server. I don't see how anyone wouldn't have made the same mistake assuming you meant client side. You shouldn't be so defensive downvoting an answer because of a simple misunderstanding. You asked a question and I gave you exactly what you asked for while others (who saw the same mistakes I did), simply closed your question ..... your welcome

Comment: Nothing to Reply like you kind of person.Because of person like you won't allow Others to Improve .Also you don't have any idea of sharing Knowledges.Bye

Comment: @GreyCode ok 1. I've saw what you did to my profile rep and reported you, thanks appreciate it. 2. How the hell does your last statement even make sense, I answered your question, only one who did. You have some serious problems mate